# Take input from text field and convert it into url slug on another line

Tags: jquery

There are so many threads on this topic but I just cannot get this to work for the life of me.

I am looking to take input from a form's text field and mirror it in real time in another place, but also converting it to lowercase and replacing spaces with dashes (and other regular expressions to make the input look like a URL).

https://jsfiddle.net/0nfybto7/1/

```
<input id="input">
<p id="slug"></p>

<script>
$('#input').on("change keyup paste click", function() {
  var Text = $(this).val();
  Text = Text.toLowerCase();
  Text = Text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, '-');
  $('#slug').val(Text);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi instead of `.val` use `.text` because `p` tag doesn't have value attribute .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.val()** in jQuery works only with input fields, for p tag use **.text()**.

so change

```
$('#slug').val(Text);
```

To

```
$('#slug').text(Text);
```

Comment: Thanks. Got it to work with your help! Will mark answer as accepted